# How can I use Heap access method in Berkeley DB 5.2.28

Tags: java, berkeley-db

hi i am using Berkeley DB Java Edition DB API
so how can I use heap access method instead of Btree access method.

Answer (score 0):

This was also asked and answered on the Berkeley DB Java Edition OTN Forum: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2261450&tstart=0

The [Heap access method](http://bit.ly/qkEgys) was introduced in the [Oracle Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/hwYyw9) 11.2.5.2 release. You can access the Heap access method through the C or Java APIs. [Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/gXs3rg), which is a separate product, only supports the B-tree access method.

Regards,

Dave